# Cross Object Field(Picklist) Update

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

Can anyone help me with writing a trigger on cross object field update.

Object: Booking__c               Field: Booking_Type__c (is a picklist)

Object: Booking_Item__C          Field: Booking_type__c (is also a picklist)

The requirement is, when status (Booking_Type_*c) of **Booking***_c is selected as *cancelled* the status (Booking_Type__c ) of **Booking_item__c** should also be updated to *cancelled*.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to make an assumption that your objects have the following relationship

`Booking_item__c.Booking__c` (Booking_item_*c record has a lookup to Booking*_c)

```apex
Trigger Booking on Booking__c (after insert, after update) {
    Set<Id> cancelledBookingIds = new Set<Id>(); 
    for (Booking__c booking: Trigger.new) {
        if (booking.Booking_Type__c == 'cancelled') {
            cancelledBookingIds.add(booking.id);
        }    
    }
    List<Booking_Item__c> bookingItemsForCancelling = [SELECT Booking_Type__c
                                                       FROM Booking_Item__c
                                                       WHERE Booking__c IN: cancelledBookingIds];
    for (Booking_Item__c item: bookingItemsForCancelling) {
        item.Booking_Type__c = 'cancelled';
    }
    update bookingItemsForCancelling;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code pavel. Booking_C is the master and Booking_Item__c is the child.